# performance comparison - pcap file reading: C++'s ifstream VS C's fread

Tags: c++, c, performance, pcap

I was researching around which one is a faster binary file reader : C++'s ifstream::read or C's fread.

According to the internet, **including similiar questions**, there is not much difference, so I decided to dig dipper.

I used a 1.22gb pcap file, which contains about 1,377,000 packets.
Both programs compiled using mingw32-g++ , no optimizations.

header structs are defined according to wireshark's wiki - libpcap file structure:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat

This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>

/* definition of structs: pcap_global_header, pcap_packet_header, ethernet_header, ipv4_header, tcp_header */

int main()
{
    int count = 0, bytes_read;

    /* open file */
    FILE * file = fopen("test.pcap", "rb");

    /* read file header */
    struct pcap_global_header gheader;

    fread(&gheader, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct pcap_global_header), file);

    // if not ethernet type
    if(gheader.network != 1)
    {
        printf("not ethernet !\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read packets */
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(gheader.snaplen);

    struct pcap_packet_header pheader;
    struct ether_header eth;
    struct ipv4_header ip;
    struct tcp_header tcp;

    fread(&pheader, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct pcap_packet_header), file);

    while(!feof(file))
    {
        ++count;

        bytes_read = fread(&eth, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct ether_header), file);

        // ip
        if(eth.type == 0x08)
        {
            bytes_read += fread(&ip, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct ipv4_header), file);

            //tcp
            if( ip.protocol == 0x06 )
            {
                bytes_read += fread(&tcp, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct tcp_header), file);
            }
        }

        //read rest of the packet
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), pheader.incl_len - bytes_read, file);

        // read next packet's header
        fread(&pheader, sizeof(char), sizeof(struct pcap_packet_header), file);
    }

    printf("(C) total packets: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

#include <Winsock2.h>

/* definition of structs: pcap_global_header, pcap_packet_header, ethernet_header, ipv4_header, tcp_header */

int main()
{
    int count_packets = 0, bytes_read;

    /* open file */
    std::ifstream file("test.pcap", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in);

    /* read file header */
    struct pcap_global_header gheader;

    file.read((char*)&gheader, sizeof(struct pcap_global_header));

    // if not ethernet type
    if(gheader.network != 1)
    {
        printf("not ethernet !\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read packets */
    char *buffer = std::allocator<char>().allocate(gheader.snaplen);

    struct pcap_packet_header pheader;
    struct ether_header eth;
    struct ipv4_header ip;
    struct tcp_header tcp;

    file.read((char*)&pheader, sizeof(pcap_packet_header));

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        ++count_packets;

        file.read((char*)&eth, sizeof(struct ether_header));
        bytes_read = sizeof(struct ether_header);

        // ip
        if(eth.type == 0x08)
        {
            file.read((char*)&ip, sizeof(struct ipv4_header));
            bytes_read += sizeof(struct ipv4_header);

            //tcp
            if( ip.protocol == 0x06 )
            {
                file.read((char*)&tcp, sizeof(struct tcp_header));
                bytes_read += sizeof(struct tcp_header);
            }
        }

        // read rest of the packet
        file.read(buffer, pheader.incl_len - bytes_read);

        // read next packet's header
        file.read((char*)&pheader, sizeof(pcap_packet_header));
    }

    std::cout << "(C++) total packets :" << count_packets << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results are very disappointing:

C code result:

```
(C) total packets: 1377065

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.031 s
Press any key to continue.
```

C++ code result:

```
(C++) total packets :1377065

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.172 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Obviously, I ran each version a couple of times, and so, I am looking for a faster way to read files using C++.

Comment: *I am looking for a faster way to read files using C++.*  You found it - use `::fread()`.  Also, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: No optimizations? Why would you benchmark this with no optimizations?

Comment: @AndrewHenle am I using feof() wrong?

Comment: @J.Doe *am I using feof() wrong?*  Yes.  Read the linked question and the answers.  `feof()` isn't true until *after* an attempt to read past the end of a file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I read the first packet's header before the call to feof(), nothing is wrong here

Comment: @J.Doe *nothing is wrong here*  Really?  There are many things wrong in your code.  Your `while(!feof(file))` loop, you call `fread()`, ignore the result, assume it worked, use the contents of the `eth` buffer whether or not `fread()` failed or succeeded, then make two or three *more* calls to `fread()` where you again *ignore* the results, any one of which can fail or run into an end-of-file condition.  Again, *read* [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifstream::read()` copies data from the internal buffer to your buffer. It cause the main difference in performance. You could try to overcome it and replace internal buffer with your own via [`pubsetbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf):

```
std::ifstream file;
char buf[1024];
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof buf);
```

Problem is that this function is implementation defined and in most cases you still need to use extra data copy.

In your case you don't need all the power of the `ifstream`, so for performance and simplicity I suggest to use `<cstdio>`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all the power of ifstream' ? What is it good for if it fails in speed?

Comment: @J.Doe Not everyone needs best possible performance. `ifstream` implements high level `std::basic_istream`, so you could use it as an input stream. There is a number of useful std algorithms that could be used for `ifstream`, e.g. `std::transform`, iterators, etc. All of it make life simpler in many cases but not always.

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` should always be faster because it reads the bytes directly into your buffer without extra processing (which is not needed here).

Also, it might be better to read the whole packet at once instead of calling `fread()` 4 times for each packet. You can then use an `ether_header*` on your buffer for example.

Using `mmap()` instead of `fread()` should give you an extra speedup (no need to copy data from kernel mode to user mode buffer). For Windows see `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` - this allows you to access the file contents directly with pointers as if it was one big memory buffer.